Online story about an alien invasion taking place in the Pacific Ocean from the view of a modern US destroyer
I remember reading maybe the first 2 or 3 chapters of this around maybe 2018. It wasn’t too long ago. It was online and had its own dedicated website and URL. It was told from the POV of a navy captain on what I am pretty positive was an Arleigh Burke.
The first chapter involved a confrontation between 1 Taiwanese and 3 Chinese naval vessels. Eventually something goes hot and the US destroyer starts shooting up the Chinese vessels with the assistance of a US submarine. There were no aliens in the first few chapters. Anyways I got bored of it and I suppose I foolishly cleared my history and could never recover it.

Can you remember any of the character names?

Dijkgraaf, no I cannot remember any characters. I know that the chief engineer on the US ship was Chinese. Name might have been Lee? Don’t see how that would help identification however
